# How to use "this" in javascript to add another child div inside a hovered div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, sorry for my English.
I don't know how to use **"this"** in my code to add a div inside the hovered div.
What happens with my code is that, whenever i hover into anyone of them the child div is added to both the div's.
But, i  want the child div to be added only to the hovered div.
I hope you understand my problem.

**Here's my html**

```
<div class="maindiv">
<img src="IMG_1212.JPG" height="200" width="200">
<div class="childdiv">
<img src="key172.png" width="35" height="35">
</div>
</div>
<div class="asd">
<img src="IMG_1071.jpg" height="200" width="200">
<div class="childdiv">
<img src="key172.png" width="35" height="35">
</div>
</div>
```

**Here's my css**

```
.maindiv{
    height:200;
    width:200;
    border:#999 2px solid;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
.maindiv:hover{
    border:#993 2px solid;
}
.childdiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: top 0.3s linear 0s, opacity 0.3s linear 0s;

}
.childdiv:hover{
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

**Here's my Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".maindiv").hover(
function(){
    $(".childdiv").css("opacity",".5");
    $(".childdiv").css("top","15px");
},
function(){
    $(".childdiv").css("opacity","0");
    $(".childdiv").css("top","20px");
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find child of `this`, the element which invoked the event.

```
$(this).find(".childdiv").css("opacity",".5")
```

OR, context selector

```
$(".childdiv", this).css("opacity",".5")
```

Comment: I'm very new to javascript. I am not getting it.

Comment: @SushangNirola, like `$(this).find(".childdiv").css("opacity",".5")`